# unallocation and copy failed even if allocation works

Tags: c++, qt, mtp

I'm currently working on a mac application to the transfer file from mac to mtp device such as usb.

I use the code below to add it:

```
LIBMTP_file_t *genfile;

char *AbsolutePath = NULL;
char *FileNameOnly = NULL;

QFileInfo fileInfo(filename);

FileNameOnly = convertQStr2char(fileInfo.fileName());
AbsolutePath = convertQStr2char(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());

genfile = LIBMTP_new_file_t();

genfile->filesize = filesize;
genfile->filename = FileNameOnly;
genfile->filetype = file_type;
genfile->parent_id = CurrentFolderID;
genfile->storage_id = PulsDeviceMngr->devicestorage->id;

if ((genfile->filetype != LIBMTP_FILETYPE_ALBUM) && (genfile->filetype != LIBMTP_FILETYPE_PLAYLIST)) {
    ret = LIBMTP_Send_File_From_File(PulsDeviceMngr->device, AbsolutePath, genfile, ProgressBar, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        qDebug() << "Error sending file";
        LIBMTP_Dump_Errorstack(PulsDeviceMngr->device);
        LIBMTP_Clear_Errorstack(PulsDeviceMngr->device);
    } else {
        PulsDeviceMngr->devicestorage->FreeSpaceInBytes -= filesize;
        PulsDeviceMngr->devicestorage->FreeSpaceInObjects--;
    }
}
LIBMTP_destroy_file_t(genfile);
```

This basically what is required by mtp to make it works.

I'm usine QT/C++ to develop the Software.

it seems that the QString is not impacted but only the char *. char* is needed because the api used only support char *. I'm converting QString to char* using the following code.

```
char *mtp_wrapper::convertQStr2char(QString str) {
    QByteArray latin_str = str.toLatin1();
    char *return_str = latin_str.data();
    return return_str;
}
```

1. I got an issue to release genfile ?? it seems that the runtime consider that I can't free an not allocated pointer but I use to do it using the line below:

   genfile = LIBMTP_new_file_t();
   LIBMTP_destroy_file_t(genfile);

There is no precondition to do it. when genfile happens, destroy happened. Some data are allocated on the genfile.

2. I'm able now to open the file for PTP stat complain that I can not send object

Any idea ?

Comment: The pointer returned by `QByteArray(filename_stripped).data();` becomes invalid immediately, so your program is undefined. Use a variable, not a temporary object.

Comment: I have made some change. but why it became invalid ?

Comment: It becomes invalid because the `QByteArray` object that owns the data it points to is destroyed before you assign the pointer to anything.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the `convertQStr2char()` method. The `latin_str` object is created on the stack and will be destroyed at the end of the enclosing code block. This object is responsible for management of its internal data.

When you call `char *return_str = latin_str.data();`, you only copy the *pointer* to `latin_str`'s internal data. As your method returns, `latin_str` is destroyed and [the memory pointed to by `data()` is freed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#data), so your returned pointer now points to a freed memory as well.

`LIBMTP_destroy_file_t` [is documented](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/mtp_files.3.html) to deallocate memory used by the structure, *including any strings*. In particular, when you call it, it also tries to free the memory pointed to by `FileNameOnly`, but - as I explained above - the memory has been already freed by `QByteArray`'s destructor, hence the error.

Since [using freed pointer results in an undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367662/3882408), this may be also the cause of your second issue.